# Openldap, "olcOverlay={0}ppolicy,cn=olcDatabase{1}mdb,cn=config" ldap_add: No such object (32)

Tags: openldap

I try to enable ppolicy in openldap. I have tried it with the following tutorial: https://tobru.ch/openldap-password-policy-overlay/

**Steps I have done:**

1. Load the ppolicy schema into OLC --> Success
2. Load the module --> Succcess
3. Configure ppolicy overlay --> Failed

**Step 3:**

`ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f ppolicycfgOverlay-add.ldif`

```
#File: ppolicycfgOverlay-add.ldif
dn: olcOverlay={0}ppolicy,cn=olcDatabase{1}mdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcPPolicyConfig
olcOverlay: {0}ppolicy
olcPPolicyDefault: cn=default,ou=policies,dc=ldap,dc=example,dc=net
olcPPolicyHashCleartext: FALSE
olcPPolicyUseLockout: TRUE
olcPPolicyForwardUpdates: FALSE
```

throws error:

```
adding new entry "olcOverlay={0}ppolicy,cn=olcDatabase{1}mdb,cn=config"
ldap_add: No such object (32)
        matched DN: cn=config
```

**Additional things I have tried:**

1. Adding the ppolicy entrys in database before setting up the overlay
2. Read http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch6/slapd-config.html#use-overlays

The File "olcOverlay={0}ppolicy" does not exist in the slapd cfg directory. But I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake:

The dn was wrong: `cn=olcDatabase{1}mdb` has to be `olcDatabase={1}mdb`.

So the correct dn is: `dn: olcOverlay={0}ppolicy,olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config`.